# How to return saved entity from mysql database

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I made saving the entity in the database.

```
    public async saveTask(toDoDto: CreateToDoDto) {
        try {
            const toDo: ToDo = this.todosRepository.create(toDoDto);
            return await this.todosRepository
                .createQueryBuilder()
                .insert()
                .into(ToDo)
                .values(toDo)
                .execute();
        } catch (err) {
            this.logger.error(err.message);
            throw new WsException(err.message);
        }
    }
```

When I save an entity to a database, I want it to be returned to me.

How can I get the just saved entity in the database?

---

```
return await this.todosRepository
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(ToDo)
    .values(toDo)
    .returning('*')
    .execute();
```

I cannot use the return function, as I get an error.

> OUTPUT or RETURNING clause only supported by Microsoft SQL Server or PostgreSQL databases.

When I insert into the database without the return function, I get the following response.

```
InsertResult {
    identifiers: Array(1),
    generatedMaps: Array(1),
    raw: OkPacket
}
```

And in this in the answer there is no entity that I wrote to the database.

How to get the recorded entity into the database if the return function is not working fuck mysql?

Answer (score -7):

(MySQLi Object-oriented)

`$last_id = $conn->insert_id;` // $conn is the connection made to sql

(MySQLi Procedural)

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

(PDO)

```
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: As I understand it, this implementation is in php. But I use nestjs